# Sagemaker pipeline join parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sagemaker

I'm working on the sagemaker pipeline, which has `PySparkProcessor` as Processing job.

I have set the arguments using `ContainerArguments`. I'm terraforming this sagemaker pipeline.

The [arguments](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/processing.html#sagemaker.spark.processing.PySparkProcessor.run) are static, but I have to join the few date parameters ( which would be set like triggering the pipeline ) and want to join these with static arguments.

```
{
   "Version":"2020-12-01",
   "Metadata":{
      
   },
   "Parameters":[
           {
               "Name": "date1",
               "Type": "String",
               "DefaultValue": ""
           },
           {
                "Name": "date2",
                "Type": "String",
                "DefaultValue": ""
           }
   ],
"PipelineExperimentConfig":{
      "ExperimentName":{
         "Get":"Execution.PipelineName"
      },
      "TrialName":{
         "Get":"Execution.PipelineExecutionId"
      }
   },
"Steps":[
      {
         "Name":"ProcessingStep",
         "Type":"Processing",
         "Arguments":{
            "ProcessingResources":{
               "ClusterConfig":{
                  "InstanceType":"${instance_type}",
                  "InstanceCount":${instance_count},
                  "VolumeSizeInGB":${vol_size}
               }
            },
            "AppSpecification":{
               "ImageUri":"${acc_id}.dkr.ecr.${region}.amazonaws.com/${image}:${image_version}",
               "ContainerArguments":[${arguments}],
               "ContainerEntrypoint":[${entry_point}]
            },
            "RoleArn":"${role_arn}",
            "ProcessingInputs":[
               {
                  "InputName":"conf",
                  "AppManaged":false,
                  "S3Input":{
                     "S3Uri":"${s3_path}",
                     "LocalPath":"/opt/ml/processing/input/conf",
                     "S3DataType":"S3Prefix",
                     "S3InputMode":"File",
                     "S3DataDistributionType":"FullyReplicated",
                     "S3CompressionType":"None"
                  } 
               },
            "Environment":{
               
            }
         },
         "CacheConfig":{
            "Enabled":true,
            "ExpireAfter":"${cache_expiration_period}"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to join the parameters - date1 and date2 with ContainerArguments -  `${arguments}`, these arguments are `list[str]`. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Are you using the SageMaker Python SDK to generate the JSON file? What key do you want to set with the joined Pipeline Params and ContainerArguments ?

Comment: Yes, Im using Python SDK. I used "," as join key. But the Join function would send me the string delimited with ",". I need array[string]. is it possible?